# Multiple models with separate search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have a Rails app with a Pins model and a Posts model. I have search set up and working great for the pins on the main page. (see the code below) I'm now adding a blog to the site and I want to search the posts on the blog page. If I copy the code below all over to the blog, (the model, controller, and view info), the url changes to

```
http://localhost:3000/posts?search=searchterm
```

but the posts don't react on the page. Do I need to give "search" a different method name in the posts model, so it doesn't interfere with the one in the pins model? Is there something else I'm doing wrong?

My search code in my working pins model:

Model: (and yes, I changed the attributes that it searches when pasting it in the new posts model)

```
def self.search(search)
 if search
  losearch = search.downcase
  find(:all, :conditions => ['lower(description) LIKE ? OR lower(artist) LIKE ? OR lower(album) LIKE ? OR lower(year) LIKE ?', "%#{search.downcase}%", "%#{search.downcase}%", "%#{search.downcase}%", "%#{search.to_s.downcase}%"], order: "created_at desc")
 else
  find(:all, order: "created_at desc")
 end
end
```

controller: (I changed all mention of pin, to post)

```
def index
 @pins = Pin.search(params[:search])
 @pins = @pins.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50)

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @pins }
  # format.js
 end
end
```

view:

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
     <div class="input-group pull-right">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search" id="search">
         <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
         </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Why don't you try looking in the `log/development.log` file what's happening when you visit http://localhost:3000/posts?search=searchterm. The log file will tell you if a search is being performed in the database. If not, there should be a clear difference between the log output for the Pin and the Post.

Comment: I had done that, but I wasn't finding anything. To my surprise, when I went back to it today it worked! One of those computer mysteries I guess. Thanks for the help.